# Is the number of map tasks determined by the number of nodes in hadoop in case the input is small in size or is part of the hardware idle?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a basic mapreduce question.
My input consists of many small files and I have designed a custom CombinedFileInputFormat (which is working properly).

The size of all files together is only like 100 Mb for 20 000 files, but processing an individual file takes a couple of minutes (it's a heavy indexing problem), therefore I want as many map tasks as possible. Will hadoop take care of this or do I have to enforce it and how? In the latter case my first guess would be to manipulate the maximum split size but I am not sure if I am on the right track. Any help greatly appreciated! (suggestions on how to set the split size best in the latter case are also helpful)

Some extra information to be more clear:

There is however another reason I wanted to process multiple files per task and that is that I want to be able to use combiners. The output of a single task only produces unique keys, but between several files there might be a substantial overlap. By processing multiple files with the same map task I can implement a combiner or make use of in-mapper combining. This would definitely limit the amount of IO. The fact is that although a single file has a size of a couple of kilobytes the output of this file is roughly 30 * 10^6 key-value pairs which easily leads to a couple of Gigabytes. 
I don't think there is another way to allow combining (or in-mapper combining) if you have only one file per maptask?

Regards, Dieter

Comment: If you have 20000 input files, Hadoop will process them using at least 20000 mappers. The number of mappers running simultaneously would be liited by the size of the cluster. Hadoop is really good at processing large files. You might be disappointed in it perfromance when if fiddles with 5KB files.

Comment: That's why I implemented CombineFileInputFormat, it takes mutiple files inside 1 split. So this is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question too fast and missed that you are already using CombinedFileInputFormat. Looks like most sources, including The Definitive Guide by Tom White, advise to set the mapred.max.split.size to a small multiple of the number of blocks times the block size in bytes. If you are using default 64MB blocks, you probably can spin off 2 mappers. If you are using more common 128MB block size, you might be out of luck given the size of your data set.

Comment: Is it possible to use very small block sizes for example 1kb and then use split sizes which are for example 100 kb? That would definitely solve some of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the best utilization for your long running map tasks, you'll probably want each file to run in it's own task rather than using your implementation of CombineInputFormat.

Using combine input format is usually advisable when you have small files that are quickly processed as it takes longer to instantiate the map task (jvm, config etc) than it does to process the file itself. You can alleviate this you by configuring 'JVM reuse', but still for a CPU bound tasks (as opposed to an IO bound tasks) you'll just want to run map tasks for each input file.

You will however need your Job Tracker to have a good chunk of memory allocated to it so it can manage and track the 20k map tasks created.

**Edit:** In response to your updated question, if you want to use combined input format then you'll need to set the configuration properties for min / max size per node / rack. Hadoop won't be able to do anything more intelligible than try and keep files that are data local or rack local together in the same map task.

Comment: Dear Chris, thanks for the hints, I editted the post to explain that I want to use combiners. The mappers generate alot of key value pairs so the problem is rather memory bound (although not on the input but rather the intermediate key-values)

Comment: Maybe it would be easier just to concatenate the files according to some distribution. Suppose I have 20 000 files, I could generate 1000 files with 10 units, 1000 with 5, 1000 with 3 and 2000 with 1 for example, this would allow some flexibility in the load balancing. (I've chosen the numbers arbitrarily, they definitely can be chosen better). Do you think this is to be preferred over the combinedformat?

Comment: Not really, as the 10 unit files will take ~10x longer than the 1 unit files. If you think about it running 10 x 1 unit tasks in parallel should be quicker than a single 10 unit task (assuming you have at least 10 map slots in your cluster).

Comment: Yes but the grouping would be to allow some combiner usage, since combiners work on the output of a single map task right? I wanted to add some file with less units to make sure that the cluster doesn't end up waiting for a single task (having 100 units for example). But probably hadoop doesn't automatically process largest files first I guess.